# Having been charmed

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Is the following sentence correct?

> Having been charmed with the silk, my sister bought ten yards.

I think the sentence is correct, because there is a chronology of events.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.  Present participle phrases like this can be tricky.  Your example does create a kind of "chronology of events", as you say, but linguistically the phrase acts as an adjective modifying "my sister".  A similar example:

> **Shaking with determination**, Sam insisted he would go with Frodo on the adventure.

Here "shaking with determination" modifies Sam, in that it describes what he is also doing at that time.

[More about participle phrases](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm)